# Fedora, keyboard input source switching impossible

Tags: linux, keyboard, fedora, language, input-languages

I have two keyboard input sources (English and Persian languages) on my machine running Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug). It starts normally but after a while working with Persian it would be impossible to switch the language back to English.

In that situation I have tried clicking on the languages menu on the toolbar and trying to switch the language, using the keyboard shortcuts and even removing the active input source in Fedora settings, none of them will change the language.

Even after locking the computer, when I try to login again, the language is Persian while entering the password and can't be switched back to English. The only way I have found to fix that (excepting restart) is to select "Login as alternative user". That time the language is set back to English and after logging in I can continue with English.

Are there any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score -2):

I change input sources from <kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> in Gnome Tweak Tool. It works in versions newer then Fedora 18 (haven't tested in Fedora 22).